# Background and jumping in Javascript canvas game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I 'm creating a Javascript Game and i was wondering if anyone could help me with adding a background to the canvas and if someone can fix my jump because i can't  get it fixed.

Thanks! :)

Here's my JSFIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/Nielsvangils/v9hL9d3k/

```js
/*

var Player;
var Player_width;
var Player_height;
var Player_POSX;
var Player_POSY;
var Player_Gravity;
var Player_IMG;
var Player_isJUMPING;

var Block;
var Block_width;
var Block_height;
var Block_POSX;
var Block_POSY;
var Block_IMG;
var Block_Hit;

var Canvas;
var Canvas_width;
var Canvas_height;

var Score;

var Background;
var Background_IMG;

var Level;
var Gamespeed;

blok.sklambert.com/html5-canvas-game-panning-a-background/  voor hulp

*/
var PlayerX;
var Blocka;
var Ground

var canvas = document.getElementById("gamefield");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


var Gamespeed=5;
var Gravity = 0.9;
var Score = 0;
var velocity = 0.01;
var jumping;

PlayerX = new Player();
Blocka = new Block(1);
Ground = new Gameground();

setInterval(Update,20);

function startGame()
{


}

function Player()
{
 // this staat voor verwijzing naar zichzelf
 this.width = 30;
 this.height = 50;
 this.x = canvas.width/4;
 this.y = canvas.height/3*2;
 this.draw = function(){
  ctx.fillStyle="#00BFFF";
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
 }
 // JUMP function 

}
  

function Block(kolb)
{
 this.width = 20;
 this.height = 40;
 this.show = true;
 //this.x = canvas.width/2;
 this.x = canvas.width + 20;
 this.y = (canvas.height/3*2)+10;
 this.draw = function(){
  this.move();
  if(this.show){
   if(kolb==1){
    ctx.fillStyle="#000000";
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
   }
  } 
 }
 this.move = function() {
  this.x -= Gamespeed;
  this.death();
 }
 this.death = function(){
  if(this.x<=20){
   this.show = false;
  }
 }
}

function Gameground()
{
 // this staat voor verwijzing naar zichzelf
 this.width = 800;
 this.height = 149;
 this.x = 0;
 this.y = 451;
 this.draw = function(){
  ctx.fillStyle = "#00FFBF"
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
 }
 

}

function Update () {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 Blocka.draw();
 PlayerX.draw();
 
 

 // function ben je af?

 if (PlayerX.x < Blocka.x + Blocka.width &&
    PlayerX.x + PlayerX.width > Blocka.x &&
    PlayerX.y < Blocka.y + Blocka.height &&
    PlayerX.height + PlayerX.y > Blocka.y) {
    // collision detected!
 Blocka.x += 580;
 }

 Ground.draw();
}

// funtion  voor eventhandles (knopjes) zoals springen
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false); 
        
function checkKeyPressed(e) {
         if (e.keyCode == "32") { //kijkt of de spatiebalk is ingedrukt

   var interval1, interval2, velo, tijd;

  velo=0.00001;
  
  tijd= 25;


  interval1 = setInterval(plus, tijd);



  function plus()
  {

  if(velo<20)
  {
  velo += 1.5;
  }
  else
  {
  velo -= 1.5;
  }

  if(PlayerX.y > 480)
  {
  clearInterval(interval1);
  interval2 = setInterval(min, tijd);



  }

  PlayerX.y += velo;
  console.log(PlayerX.y);

  }


  function min()
  {

  if(velo<20)
  {
  velo += 1.5;
  }
  else
  {
  velo -= 1.5;
  }

  if(PlayerX.y < 430)
  {
  clearInterval(interval2);



  }

  PlayerX.y -= velo;
  console.log(PlayerX.y);

  }



}
}


// function SPAwn 
// BLOCKa vervangen door array met blokjes...
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Game</title>
<body onload="startGame()">
  <canvas id="gamefield" width="800" height="600" style="border:1px solid #000000"></canvas>
  <script src="game.js"></script>
```

Comment: For the background. Load an image and in the main loop instead of calling `ctx.clearRect` draw the image `ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height)` As for the jumping, you are using an event driven approch which is not easy to manage in frame based animation. Consider using the key events just to register which keys are pressed and then in the main loop monitor the keys pressed and do the appropriate action as required. Change`setInterval(Update,20);` to `requestAnimationFrame(Update)` and add `requestAnimationFrame(Update)` to the end of the `Update` function.

Answer (score 0):

**Adding a Background**

You can draw an image background as simply as: `context.drawImage(bkImg,0,0)`

**Jumping from A to B**

This algorithm will plot a waypoint that is `percent` of the way on the line between point `A` and point `B`.

```
var dx = B.x-A.x;
var dy = B.y-A.y;
waypointX = A.x + dx * percent;
waypointY = A.y + dy * percent;
```

Then to make a jump from `A` to `B` you can decrease the waypointY value which pushes the player upward. A convenient way to create an arc jump is to use `Math.sin` to reduce waypointY.

*Warning: Math speak:*

- `Math.sin(n)` will form a suitable arc as `n` changes from 0 to PI.
- `Math.sin(0)` and `Math.sin(PI)` will both return a value of 0.
- `Math.sin(n)` will return an decreasing value during n between 0 and PI/2 with the value minimizing at -1.00 when n=PI/2.
- `Math.sin(n)` will return an increasing value during n between PI/2 and PI with the value maximizing at 0.00 when n=PI.

*...And visually that sine wave looks like this:*

[image]

*...And visually the negative sine values make a wave that looks like this (jump!):*

[image]

So the combination of `waypointY` and the negative sine values will create a "jump".

```
waypointX=A.x + dx*percent;
// Note: The 50 in the next line tells the player how high to jump
waypointY=A.y + dy*pct - Math.sin(percent*Math.PI)*50;
```

You can control the height of the jump by multiplying the `Math.sin` by a maximum (apex) height that you want your player to jump.

**Here's example code and a Demo**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    offsetX=BB.left;
    offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var isJumping=false;

var player={x:20,y:100,sx:0,sy:0,dx:0,dy:0,pct:100};

var bk=new Image();
bk.onload=start;
bk.src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/googlemap1.png';
var playerImg=new Image();
playerImg.onload=start;
playerImg.src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/marioRunningRightSmall.png';
var imgCount=2;
function start(){
    if(--imgCount>0){return;}
    cw=canvas.width=bk.width;
    ch=canvas.height=bk.height;
    draw();

    $myslider=$('#myslider');
    $myslider.attr({min:0,max:100}).val(0);
    $myslider.on('input change',function(){
        player.pct=parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});

}

function draw(){
    ctx.drawImage(bk,0,0);
    ctx.drawImage(playerImg,player.x,player.y);
}

function jumpToXY(x,y){
    player.sx=player.x;
    player.sy=player.y-playerImg.height;
    player.dx=x-player.x;
    player.dy=y-player.y;
    player.pct=0;
    isJumping=true;
    requestAnimationFrame(animateJump);
}

function animateJump(){
    draw();
    player.pct+=4;
    var pct=player.pct/100;
    if(player.pct<=100){
        player.x=player.sx+player.dx*pct;
        player.y=player.sy+player.dy*pct-Math.sin(pct*Math.PI)*25;
        requestAnimationFrame(animateJump);
    }else{
        isJumping=false;
    }
}

function handleMouseDown(e){
    // if animation is in progress just return
    if(isJumping){return;}
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // jump to mouse
    mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
    mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
    jumpToXY(mouseX,mouseY);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Click on the map to make Mario jump to that click point</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: I truly admire how much work you put into every single answer--it's astonishing. :O